# JavaScript Event Listener To Rediredct Page After Form Submission

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am trying to make my webpage redirect to a thank you page after a user submits my registration form.

Below is the javascript event listener that I have been trying to use but not working.
Any help will be appreciated.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const form = document.getElementById('submitForm');
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form);
    const action = e.target.action;
    fetch(action, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    })
    .then(() => {
      alert("https://www.google.com/");
    })
  });
});
```

```html
   <div class='testbox'>
      <form action='https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyg4V7O2BTMG_u1QVROTCVhZlDo2viq3e2bcqjQ9X6ZBOCyBoQrkyJGK1Zw_gtFp6dw/exec' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
      
    <div class='name-item'>
            <input name='Surname' placeholder='Surname' required='' type='text'/>
            <input name='First Name' placeholder='First Name' required='' type='text'/>
             <input name='Middle Name' placeholder='Middle Name' required='' type='text'/>
           </div>
      
        
      <div class='question'>
          <center><p>Privacy Policy<span class='required'>*</span></p></center>
          <div class='question-answer checkbox-item'>
            <div>
              
              <center><label class='check' for='check_1'><span>By submitting this form you agree to the terms of service <a href='https://www.google.com/p/privacy-policy.html' target="_blank">privacy policy.</a></span></label></center>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='btn-block'>
         <center> <button href='/' type='submit' id="submitForm">Submit</button></center>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> const form = document.getElementById('submitForm');
> ```
>
> ```
> <form action='...' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
> ```

Your `<form>` element does not have an `id`, so you cannot use `getElementById` to reference it.

You either need to add an `id` to your form:

```
<form action='...' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" id="submitForm">
```

or use `querySelector` to reference it:

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
```

**NB:** If you have multiple `<form>` elements in your page, `querySelector` will only return the first one.